# Why wp_video_shortcode inside shortcode echoes when calling the wrapping shortcode?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a shortcode, which returns html created like this:

```
public function get_video_grid($the_query) {
    $html = '';
    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $count = 0;
        while ( $the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post();
            $attachment = get_attached_media( 'video' );
            $post_ID = get_the_ID();

            global $wpdb;
            $video_url =  wp_get_attachment_url($post_ID);

            $video_attr = array(
                'src' => $video_url
            );

            $item = $wpdb->get_row(
                "
                    SELECT video_start_time
                    FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "lc
                    WHERE attachment_id = $post_ID
                ",
                ARRAY_A
            );

            $time = $item['video_start_time'];
            $html .= '<div class="video-thumb-wrapper">';
            $html .= '<h4 class="grid-title">' . get_the_title() . '</h4>';
            $html .= '<span class="grid-timestamp">' . gmdate('d.m.Y H:i', strtotime($time)) . '</span>';
            $html .= '<div class="aspect-ratio">';
            $html .= wp_video_shortcode( $video_attr );
            $html .= '</div>';
            $html .= '</div>';
            $count++;
        endwhile;
    }
    return $html;
} // get_video_grid
```

However, if I am using the shortcode either in article or in do_shortcode(), the video elements are rendered outside of the containers on some pages. On some WP installations this works just fine. The version of WP does not seem to affect.

If I try to store the html string to variable like this:

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Modular Page
 */
get_header(); ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

    if ( post_password_required() ) {
        echo get_the_password_form();
    } else {
        lobo_modular_content( $post );
    }

    endwhile;
    $content = do_shortcode("[lilicast_list]");
get_footer(); ?>
```

the videos are still rendered. Notable here is that nothing should be echoed at this point, yet still I have the elements in my html. As far as I know, all I am asking is the wp to return me a string.

Why is the wp_video_shortcode() echoed before anything else? Why the behaviour is not consistent with just adding the shortcode inside of the post?

Comment: Please attach code in which you are inserting shortcode.

Comment: @KrzysztofJaniszewski Not understanding. Do you mean the add_shortcode?

Comment: No I mean file in which you have this `$content = do_shortcode("[lilicast_list]");`

Comment: @KrzysztofJaniszewski Done

Comment: I see. It looks like it is a different problem than I expected. I will see to it today  in the evening (right now I am unable to test few things). Maybe someone else will help you earlier.